# Importing from Excel to SQL Server: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, excel, import

I have the following Excel Workbook:

https://meocloud.pt/link/7cb3ef48-7556-4d36-ab9a-c247d3f7b29d/FichasTeste.xls/

It's formatted to be imported to a SQL Database. The server has the following details:

[image: SQL Properties]

As you can see the mapping is correct in the importer
[image: Mapping]

When i try to import the excel file, the status is always the same, no matter the modifications i do to the columns with the Date.

> 242: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>
> 3621: The statement has been terminated.

What should i modify so that those rows can be imported without having that error?

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as integers, if you change the excel field to `TEXT` you'll see that, but I'm not sure why you're having this problem, you should be able to direclty import from Excel and have dates preserved, at least you can using SQL's import wizard as well as SSIS.

One workaround is using the `TEXT()` function in Excel to get your date into an acceptable format:

```
=TEXT(F2,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

I like importing from Excel using `OPENROWSET()`, but that requires some additional setup and has it's own drawbacks:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\YourExcelFile.xls', [Sheet1$])
```

Comment: Unfortunatly using the TEXT() doesn't help. Using the profiler, i see that the dates are always going for example like '1/1/2013' instead of that format.